# What's the meaning of cipher's `IV Length`?

Tags: ciphers

What's the meaning of IV length?

there provide several stream ciphers, what's the meaning of `IV Length`?

```
Name          Key Size        IV Length
aes-128-ctr   16              16
aes-192-ctr   24              16
aes-256-ctr   32              16
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IV means `initialization vector`, in cipher, it is a fixed-size input value. the cipher method can use it for `non-repeating` and `randomness` function.

You can also find more on Wiki[Initialization Vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector).